# Proof product topology has a countable basis

Tags: general-topology

$(X,T_{X})$ and $(Y,T_{Y})$ are topological spaces

We define the product topology as the family of unions of the sets in $\mathfrak{B}=\left \{ U \times V:U \in T_{X}, V \in T_{Y} \right \}$

If If $(X,T_{X})$ and $(Y,T_{Y})$ have countable bases $\mathfrak{B}_{X},\mathfrak{B}_{Y}$ respectively. Is this a correct proof that the product topology has a countable basis:

$\mathfrak{B}_{X \times Y}= \left \{ (x,y):x \in \mathfrak{B}_{X}, y \in \mathfrak{B}_{Y} \right \}$ is a countable basis for $\mathfrak{B}$.

Therefore, $\mathfrak{B}_{X \times Y}$ is a countable basis for $T_{X \times Y}$ as required?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You just need to prove that this is indeed a basis for $X\times Y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One minor mistake would be that $\mathfrak B_{X\times Y}$ is a collection of subsets of $X\times Y$, and not a collection of ordered pairs.

Regardless to the above, if you have proved before that the product of bases is a basis for the product topology, and that the product of two countable sets is countable, then this is a correct proof.

If you haven't, then you should probably fill in the missing gaps.

Answer (score 1):

You have some type confusion regarding the definition of $\mathfrak{B}_{X \times Y}$.

A better definition: $\mathfrak{B}_{X \times Y} = \{ U \times V: U \in \mathfrak{B}_X, V \in \mathfrak{B}_Y \}$.

This is countable when $\mathfrak{B}_X$ and $\mathfrak{B}_Y$ are.

If $(x,y) \in O$, $O$ product open, then there are open sets $O_1 \subset X$ and $O_2 \subset Y$ such that $(x,y) \in O_1 \times O_2 \subset O$.

As $\mathfrak{B}_X$ is a base for $X$, there is some $U \in \mathfrak{B}_X$ such that $x \in U \subset O$, etc....