# Prove topological space has countable basis

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-analysis, second-countable

Given a topological subspace M of $\mathbb{R}^2 \times S^1$ defined by $(x,y,e^{i\theta})$ and two charts $(U,h)$, $(V,k)$ such that
$H:\mathbb{R} \times (-\pi,\pi) \to M$
$H(x,\theta) = (x,x\tan(\frac{\theta}{2}),e^{i\theta}) U= \operatorname{im}(H)$, $h= H^{-1}$
$K:\mathbb{R} \times (0,2\pi) \to M$
$K(y,\theta) = (y\cot(\frac{\theta}{2}),y,e^{i\theta}) V= \operatorname{im}(K), k= K^{-1}$

I've shown that $M$ is Hausdorff but how do I prove that it has a countable basis, $M = U\cup V$, and that the transition map and its inverse are differentiable.

Comment: What's $M$? I realised I'm quite lost in all that messy text.

Comment: Sorry M is the subspace. I will edit.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Topological subspaces of N2 spaces are automatically N2. $\Bbb R^2\times S^1$ is N2 (either [because both $\Bbb R^2$ and $S^1$ are N2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763110/proof-product-topology-has-a-countable-basis?rq=1) or, if you like it better, because $\Bbb R^2\times S^1\subseteq \Bbb R^4$ ).

Comment: could you elaborate on what you mean by an N2 space?

Comment: N2 = [second countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space). Sorry, I thought it was a widely used terminology, but it appears not to be the case.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I wonder whether you have some book (or some other source), where the terminology $N_1$, $N_2$ is used. I am also curious whether there are some other properties denoted as $N_i$. I have asked about this here: [Are the names such as $N_1$-space, $N_2$-space used for various countability axioms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1310817#comment5247244_1310817)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Uhm... I wouldn't know, actually. I recall hearing it at my first course in topology and deciding that, for once, it made a lot of sense (in Italian, "countable" is "numerabile"). Looking back, even the textbook we used at the time consistently adopts the terms "first/second-countable". At this point, I suspect it might have just been an idea of either the professor, or the instructor, or even our own as students. However, I'm under the impression that in the university I've studied people do not ask for clarification when one says "N2" (or I'd have noticed).

Comment: Any subspace of a 2nd-countable space is 2nd-countable. The product of two 2nd-countable spaces is 2nd-countable..... $ \Bbb R$ is 2nd-countable so $\Bbb R^2=\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ is also. And $S^1\subset \Bbb R^2$ so $S^1$ is 2nd-countable. So $\Bbb R^2\times S^1$ is 2nd-countable, so $M$ is, because $M\subset \Bbb R^2\times S^1 .$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet If undergrad me saw this he would be extremely frustrated with himself. Anyway, thanks for the concrete response, and thanks for reminding me how much I enjoyed that class.